# How to record scheme session in a file?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to record my session while writing some scheme code, But I don't know which is the correct code to record my session while doing some expression.

Comment: Which scheme? They have different ways of configuring transcripts to dribble files.

Comment: I’m using Racket v7

Comment: If you're using DrRacket you can save the Interactions window, or copy and paste. Otherwise, [tee](https://manpage.me/?q=tee) is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## R5RS

R5RS has an optional procedure [`transcript-on`](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_632) that takes a file name and it will output the interaction until transcript-off` is called.  *(Thanks @molbdnilo for pointing this out in a comment)*

## R6RS and R7RS

This is not supported in the report. Even `(scheme-report-environment 5)‌` is specified not to contain the optional procedures `load`, `interaction-environment`, `transcript-on`, `transcript-off`, and `char-ready?`.

## Implementation lock-ins

The individual implementations might have such features included and if you just need it for you chosen implementation you must read its documentation to find it. I guess this is for tooling rather than production code so using implementation specific features isn't as bad as using non scheme standard forms.

## roll your own

You can make your own repl that does what you want with the file output of you chosing that would be the same across all implementations.